# Expo dev build failing after formatted pc [A problem occurred evaluating project :expo]

Tags: react-native, expo

I have just formatted my pc and setup all necessary stuff. Then i tried to build the expo dev app with npx expo run:android but it fails at the following section. I'm missing something but i could not figure it out.

```bash
> Configure project :app
 ??  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@2.4.8)
 ??  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-updates-gradle-plugin' (expo-updates@0.18.10)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Dev\driverbook\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\scripts\android\autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 356

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > No enum constant org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.PropertiesProvider.JvmTargetValidationMode.WARN¦NG
      > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debugAndroidTest' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU¦LD FAILED in 41s
15 actionable tasks: 15 executed
Error: D:\Dev\driverbook\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: D:\Dev\driverbook\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (D:\Dev\driverbook\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\Dev\driverbook\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (D:\Dev\driverbook\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (D:\Dev\driverbook\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (D:\Dev\driverbook\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (D:\Dev\driverbook\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:35:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```